converting list of Str into list of Enums
I have an enum definition in a module AAA:
enum RDProcDebug <None All AstBlock BlockType Scoping Templates MarkUp>;

class Debug {
  method foo(RDProcDebug @ds) {
    for @ds { say .key ~ ' => ' ~ .value }
  }
}

In Raku programs, this works well, eg
use AAA;
my RDProcDebug $rp .= new;
$r.foo(AstBlock, BlockType);

But now I need to supply the names of the debug elements from the command line, which can only supply Str, eg
$ RDOpts='AstBlock BlockType' raku myprog

# and in myprog
if %*ENV<RDOpts>:exists {
  $rp.debug( %*ENV<RDOpts> ); # this does not work
}

So how do I convert a list of Str into a list of type enum RDProcDebug ?

"one can reconstruct a symbol from its name".

Okay, so you want to pass those enum values from the command line, but there you only get strings. I get it.
Here's what you can do:
First, grab that RDOpts from your environment and split it into separate words.
my @debug-options = %*ENV<RDOpts>.split(/\s+/);

Now here's the neat part. Raku has a trick to look up enum values by their name. It looks a bit weird, but it works like this:
my @debug-values = @debug-options.map({ RDProcDebug::{$_} });

What this does is check for each string in your list if there's a matching enum value. If all goes well, you'll end up with a list of actual RDProcDebug values.
You can now just pass it to your debug method:
$rp.debug(@debug-values);

All together you would get something like this:
if %*ENV<RDOpts> {
my @debug-options = %*ENV<RDOpts>.split(/\s+/);
my @debug-values = @debug-options.map({ RDProcDebug::{$_} });
$rp.debug(@debug-values);}

Oh yeah, one more thing: if someone types in a wrong name, you'll get an error. You might want to do something about that..

the .map({ RDProcDebug::{$_} }) is the secret sauce (source?) I was looking for!

It's actually a combination of a few Raku features:
The :: syntax is for accessing package-level symbols. In this case, it's looking inside the RDProcDebug enum.
The {} around $_ means we're doing a dynamic lookup. It's like saying "use the string value of $_ as the key to look up in RDProcDebug".
The .map() is just applying this to each item in your list of strings.
This isn't really documented in one specific place, because it's using a few different Raku features together.
